# How to say meeting is about my questions?

Tags: single-word-requests, expression-choice

I want to ask my supervisor for a meeting. I want to say meeting is about my questions about the approach. Can I use discuss for asking questions?

> I would be grateful for an appointment, at your convenience, to discuss my questions.

Comment: I prefer this : _...to discuss [the specific] questions I encountered with [regard to  (topic of) research]_

Answer (score 2):

"To discuss my questions" is mostly fine, and you wouldn't go badly wrong with that word choice. However, it could conceivably be misinterpreted as a request to discuss the questions themselves (as, perhaps, their wording) rather than to get answers to them. And, of course, directly demanding answers may come across as, well, demanding. An alternative might be "to discuss these topics" or even "to talk about this in person."

Answer (score 1):

If I may request you to consider a meeting [at date and time] to review my concerns [describe context].

[optional elements]